# Visual Basic Class with 2 dimensional arrays?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, class, multidimensional-array

Just picking up programming again and new to Classes and I'm trying to make 2 dimensional arrays work in a class.

I need a function to be passed the size (x,y) of two 2dimensional arrays in a Class that the function will return.

Is this possible, if so how do I Dim the ReturnVar

This isn't working code of course, just a skeleton to show what I'm after.

```
Public Class TestClass
    Public Array1(,) As Integer
    Public Array2(,) As Integer
End Class

Function MyFunc1(ByVal x as Integer, y as Integer) as TestClass
    'x and y will define the size of the two arrays in the TestClass

    Dim ReturnVar ??? As New TestClass
    .
    do some code
    .
    Return ReturnVar
End Function
```

Comment: Are you trying to learn about classes, two dimensional arrays, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it if I have understood correctly:

```
Function MyFunc1(ByVal x As Integer, y As Integer) As TestClass
    Dim ReturnVar As New TestClass
    ReDim ReturnVar.Array1(x, y)
    ReDim ReturnVar.Array2(x, y)
    Return ReturnVar
End Function
```

It would be a better idea to pass these values into the constrcutor of the TestClass I think, then it makes it obvious and you can't forget it:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Public Array1(,) As Integer
    Public Array2(,) As Integer

    Public Sub New(x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer, x2 As Integer, y2 As Integer)
        ReDim Array1(x1, y1)
        ReDim Array2(x2, y2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Your function is now so simple it doesn't need to be a function:

```
Function MyFunc1(ByVal x As Integer, y As Integer) As TestClass
    Return New TestClass(x, y, x, y)
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, that makes it look simple! :)  I guess instead of a function I could then put my code in the Public Sub New routine and fill the arrays?  Technically the array's size isn't the x and y, but x and y are used in the calculation for the array's size.  I'll try it tonight, thanks a lot!!!